# why does loading jquery after mootools causes conflicts

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering what is the reason for the conflict when jquery is loaded after mootools.
Anyone has a nice explaination since the web gives me shady answers.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because they both use the `$` character. Use [$.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) to fix

Is there a particular reason why you need to use *both* libraries?

Answer (score 3):

Use jQuery instead of $

e.g.:

```
jQuery('h1').click(function(){ alert('test'); });
```